# Delete permission for deleting for all users/groups

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I would like to grant deletion rights for a file I created to all users and groups on a machine.

At the moment I have a specific user `user_A` that creates a file with permission 0666, but if another user `user_B` tries to delete that file Linux doesn't allow that and says `no permission`.

Which numeric value should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In traditional Unix/Linux permissions, give that user write access to the directory containing the file. A person can delete any file in a directory to which they have write access.

To grant everybody permission to delete any file in a directory (and also to create files there)

```
chmod o+w directoryname
```

For finer grained controls use ACLs as described by [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-acls.html), [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) and others.